# Tesseract - Training vertical languages

Tags: tesseract, tesstrain

I can't find any documentation on vert traineddata files. What do they contain? Are they the same language model only with different configuration? Should I just be training the basic model with vertical loaded as sublanguage and that would train both?

I see `language-specific.sh` contains these lines for vertical:

```
# The following fonts will be rendered vertically in phase I.
VERTICAL_FONTS=( \
    "TakaoExGothic" \ # for jpn
    "TakaoExMincho" \ # for jpn
    "AR PL UKai Patched" \ # for chi_tra
    "AR PL UMing Patched Light" \ # for chi_tra
    "Baekmuk Batang Patched" \ # for kor
    )
```

But that's not enough info to go by